# Disable automatic disposal of Input Parameters in WCF service call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF server configured for singleton instancing.  My client is passing as a parameter to a service method, an object that implements the `IDisposable` interface and the server is attempting to cache this instance, however, the parameter is being disposed automatically by the WCF runtime at some point *after* the service method is executed , destroying my cached instance prematurely.

By looking at the stack trace,  I find that the `Dispose()` call of the parameter is being invoked inside the `MessageRpc.DisposeParametersCore()` method.

This is the reference source for that method as taken from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/MessageRpc.cs):

```
 internal void DisposeParametersCore(bool excludeInput)
        {
            if (!this.ParametersDisposed)
            {
                if (!excludeInput)
                {
                    this.DisposeParameterList(this.InputParameters);
                }
                this.DisposeParameterList(this.OutputParameters);
                IDisposable disposableParameter = this.ReturnParameter as IDisposable;
                if (disposableParameter != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        disposableParameter.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        if (Fx.IsFatal(e))
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                        this.channelHandler.HandleError(e);
                    }
                }
                this.ParametersDisposed = true;
            }
        }
```

As you can see, the disposal of the input parameters is controlled by the bool parameter `excludeInput` which hints me that this behavior is optional.

I know that if I cache a **deep copy** of the parameter it will circumvent this issue, but is there a way I can turn off this automatic behavior for a particular WCF method?

Here is the object class I am trying to cache on the server (written in C++ CLI):

```
[Serializable()]
   public ref class OpaqueMediaType : ISerializable, IConcreteMediaType {
   private:
      static const Byte _version = 1;
   private:
      clr_scoped_ptr<CComPtrIMFMediaType> _ppMediaType;
   protected:
      virtual DMO_MEDIA_TYPE* __clrcall GetConcreteDMOMediaType() sealed 
         = IConcreteMediaType::GetConcreteDMOMediaType;
      virtual CComPtrIMFMediaType __clrcall  GetConcreteMFMediaType() sealed 
         = IConcreteMediaType::GetConcreteMFMediaType;
      virtual void __clrcall FreeConcreteDMOMediaType(DMO_MEDIA_TYPE* pDMOMediaType) sealed
         = IConcreteMediaType::FreeConcreteDMOMediaType;
   protected:
      OpaqueMediaType(SerializationInfo^ info, StreamingContext context);
   public:
      OpaqueMediaType(DMO_MEDIA_TYPE& dmoMediaType);
      OpaqueMediaType(IMFMediaType* pMFMediaType);
      OpaqueMediaType(PCM_MediaType pcmMediaType);
      virtual void __clrcall GetObjectData(SerializationInfo^ info, StreamingContext context);
      PCM_MediaType AsPCM();
   };
```

The `_ppMediaType` member is taking ownership of a CComPtr derived class pointer, so when the instance is disposed, the associated COM object is released. Since this member is disposable, the `IDisposable` interface for the `OpaqueMediaType` class is automatically defined and implemented by C++/CLI.

Here is the WCF method that is caching the object:

```
 Task IStorageBackendSvc.AcceptWmaMediaType(int stationId, OpaqueMediaType mediaType) {
         try {
            WmaWriter wmaWriter = GetWmaWriter(stationId);
            wmaWriter.MediaType = mediaType;  // parameter object is cached here (shallow copy)
            return Task.CompletedTask;
         } catch( Exception exception ) {
            throw _faultFactory.Wrap(exception);
         }
// the `mediaType` parameter is being disposed by WCF at some point AFTER calling this code, releasing the internal COM object held by the cached instance prematurely
      }
```

Comment: I think I found it: `OperationBehaviorAttribute.AutoDisposeParameters`

Comment: _"...the server is attempting to cache this instance..."_ - how is it doing that? You need to show that code.  It shouldn't be hard considering your server is a singleton, just stick it in a field in the service class.  No fancy `DisposeParametersCore` is required

Comment: You do understand too that any object appearing within the WCF server's AppDomain has nothing to do with the client's represention of the object.  Even if both WCF client and server are on the `same` computer, you will have separate and distinct objects.  Changing the client won't affect the server and vice verse.   WCF is **not .NET Remoting**

Comment: @MickyD `DisposeParametersCore` is a WCF internal method,being called automatically by WCF *after* the service accepts my request. I understand too that the WCF server deserializes a copy of the parameter passed by the client, it is *that* copy that is being disposed automatically by the WCF infrastructure. I can circumvent that problem by creating and caching a deep copy of the parameter but I wanted to know If I could control this behavior in the contract.  Apparently it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorating the implementation (not the contract) of the method with `OperationBehaviorAttribute.AutoDisposeParameters = false` does the job.

Here was my contract

```
[ServiceContract]
   public interface IStorageBackendSvc {
      ...
      [OperationContract]
      [FaultContract(typeof(DescriptiveFault))]
      Task AcceptWmaMediaType(int stationId, OpaqueMediaType mediaType);

   }
```

Here is the implementation:

```
  [OperationBehavior(AutoDisposeParameters = false)]
  Task IStorageBackendSvc.AcceptWmaMediaType(int stationId, OpaqueMediaType mediaType) {
     try {
        WmaWriter wmaWriter = GetWmaWriter(stationId);
        wmaWriter.MediaType = mediaType;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
     } catch( Exception exception ) {
        throw _faultFactory.Wrap(exception);
     }
  }
```

Now the `mediaType` parameter is **not** disposed, so the cached reference is kept valid and I could bypass performing a deep copy of the parameter.

Edit: Regarding the doubts of how the object is being cached, here is the code:

```
  private Dictionary<int, WmaWriter> _wmaWriters;

  private WmaWriter GetWmaWriter(int stationId) {
         WmaWriter wmaWriter;
         lock( _wmaWriters ) {
            if( !_wmaWriters.TryGetValue(stationId, out wmaWriter) ) {
               wmaWriter = new WmaWriter(stationId, new DailyFileSplitter(), new WmaFileNameResolver(stationId));
               _wmaWriters[stationId] = wmaWriter;
            }
         }
         return wmaWriter;
      }
```

`_wmaWriters` is a service member. It is a dictionary that holds multiple WMA writers keyed by a station Id (I am recording multiple TV and radio stations) The `GetWmaWriter()` method will return an existing WMA writer associated with a specific station, or it will create a new one if none exists.  The caching is effective because for multiple calls for the same station Id, I will get the same WmaWriter instance.

Comment: I was doing some reading and the AutoDisposeParameters option can be useful during streaming.  Are you using that somewhere?

Comment: @MickyD I added the logic that is caching the `mediaType` parameter. As you can see, it is rooted, as I assign it to the MediaType property of an object whose lifetime is controlled by the service itself. The thing is that even if the object was rooted,  WCF insisted on disposing it automatically, regardless of a valid reference to it was still held.

Comment: No, no streaming in this case. Basically the WCF client specifies the quality of a WMA recording (bit-rate, sample size, sampling frequency, etc.). The client needs to relay this configuration to a remote WMA writing component, that will receive compressed audio packets from the client. This information is stored on an `OpaqueMediaType` instance, that is serializable and thus, transmittable via WCF...

Comment: (continued…) The problem was that the service was faulting when attempting to access the configuration information, since the COM object storing it had already been freed (it is stored in a managed COM smart pointer that releases a COM instance when disposed). The disposal was triggered by WCF (by auto-disposing parameters by default), not by me.

Comment: Wow OK.   Glad you got it going.  +1

Comment: @MickyD, thanks for your input. I'm sorry that I ommitted a lot of information that was necessary for proper context.   Cheers!  =D